# How to use scanf() for multidimensional char array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, scanf

I'm trying this code for entering values into multidimensional char array in C.

The code:

```
char s[2][2];
    char TRUE = '1';

for (i =0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {

        scanf("%c\n", &s[i][j]);
        printf("%c\n", (char)s[i][j]);
        printf("###\n");
        if (s[i][j] == TRUE)
            printf("Char are equal\n");
        else
            printf("Not\n");
    }
}
```

The problem is that for that first scanf(), i'm getting Null value.
This code works good only from the second scanf().

The code purpose is to enter '1' and '0' values and then compare if the input is equal to TRUE ('1').

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `if (s[i][j] == TRUE)`

Comment: are you sure, you want to put if block in the nested for loop? what do you mean by code works good?

Comment: What the hell are you typing in? And what is TRUE? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, TRUE = '1' and I'm entering '0' or '1' in the scanf(). My purpose is to check if the input equals '1'.

Comment: `TRUE`, `true`, `FALSE` and `false` are **horrible** choices for variable names unless they are const and contain the values 1/0 (and no, not as strings). But then you don't want variables but `#define`s.

Comment: its better you use getch or getchar

Comment: try removing that \n in scanf man.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - `getch` is not part of the C standard.

Comment: you are right. I've changed the TRUE  declaration to #define TRUE '1'.

Comment: @ArjunShankar yeah, I knew one my mentioned functions is not in C standard. Thats why I mentioned 2 functions. :P

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - OK. Whenever I see 'getch' I am somehow reminded of secondary school assignments and `conio.h` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with `scanf()` by default. You should call it:

```
scanf("%c", &s[i][j]);
fflush(stdin);
```

or if `fflush()` isn't available on your operating system that would be help:

```
do scanf("%c", &s[i][j]); while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Hope that helped :)